# Set the position of pop up div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a solution on how to set the position of the pop up div which is showed by click on an another div but its position depends on where the position of the window is.

Here some examples of my divs:

```
 <div id="header"></div>

 <div id="open">Click here to open the popup</div>

 <div id="popup">
      <div class="popup-wrapper">
          <div class="content">
             <h1>TEST</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>

 <div id="footer"></div>
```

**For example:**

1. If the user clicks the `#open` div to show the `#popup` div with the position of the browser's window scroll bar in the bottom, I want that `#popup` div to show at the top of the `#open` div.
2. However, if the user clicks the '#open' div to show the `#popup` div with the position of the browser's window on the top, I want that `#popup` div to show at the bottom of the `#open` div.

Here is the script that I used:

```
$("#popup").click(function(e) {
     if ($(e.target).closest(".content" /*or any other selector here*/).length > 0){
         return false;
     }
     $("#popup").fadeOut(200);
     $("body").addClass("no-scroll");
});

//This is just to open the popup
$('#open').click(function() {
    $("#popup").show();
});
```

Here is the complete code with css [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/SLW4Z/)

Comment: You can check the position of the scroll bar and display the popup accordingly.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One way to do this is not by light box div, but I can use a dropdown auto position with flip function and miror function as how discussed in here:  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10756#issuecomment-41041800

Answer (score 2):

Check the user's scroll bar position. Then display your popup depending on the scroll bar's position. Haven't tested the code below but something similar to this.

```
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;

if(scrollTop == 0){
   // Window on top. Display popup
}

if(scrollTop == $(window).height()){
   // Window on bottom. Display popup
}
```

Comment: Please look at to the screenshots I posted bellow this page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more dynamic working solution. It looks for any element with the class of 'popupSection' and opens the popup on it.

```
$('.popupSection').on('click',function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    var targetOffset = target.offset().top;
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollPosition <= targetOffset ) {
        openPopup(targetOffset);
    } else {
        var targetHeight = target.height();
        var contentHeight = $('#popup .content').outerHeight();
        var targetBottomOffset = targetOffset + targetHeight - contentHeight;
        openPopup(targetBottomOffset);
    }    
});

var openPopup = function(offset){
    var popup = $('#popup');
    var popupContent = $('#popup .content');
    if ( popup.css('display') === 'none' ) {
        popup.css('display','block');
    }
    popupContent.css('top',offset);    
}

$("#popup").click(function(e) {    
    $("#popup").fadeOut(200);
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epbdZ/2/

Comment: Almost there, but when the user clicks outset the popup div, it doesn't close the div. http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/76exm/ I update the fiddle from you.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle that closes the popup when a user clicks outside the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/76exm/1/

Comment: I found that the code is still not working as how I want it. Here is the scenario: In the fiddle, there are two colors, yellow and gray. If the 'gray color div' are in the bottom of the window, I want the popup div to show up in the upstair of the that gray color. But, I want the 'pop up div' to show up in the bellow of the gray color if the gray color is on the top of the window. Please.

Comment: I am not programmatically familiar with the term upstairs... but is this what you are asking for? Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76exm/3/

Comment: Please have a look to some screnshots bellow.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "#open" div position with event.offsetX and event.offsetY when div is clicked, then you can calculate new coordinate for popup window.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to arrange the codes. And please have a look to some screnshots I posted bellow this page. Thanks in Advance.